# shape border rotate has no effect on "tape" shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I try to rotate the shape "tape" with no effect. Please take a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[shape=tape, shape border rotate=90, draw, fill=yellow!20, text width=2cm] {A39F 47CA\\\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would expect the shape to have its curvy lines vertical but they are still horizontal, as if I would not use the `shape boarder rotate=90` at all.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve the appearence of the shape with the curvy lines vertical? What i try to achieve is something like on the picture below (but without the second sheet and written content instead of just lines):

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `transform shape`?

Comment: The pgfmanual clearly says (on p, 231 of v3.1.5) that `Some shapes (but not all), support a special kind of rotation. This rotation affects only the border of a shape and is independent of the node contents, but in addition to any other transformations.` The `tape` shape is not one of the shapes which are supported. So you can do what @HenriMenke suggest, or use `fit` for the `tape` shape, and the `rotate fit` key.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I had a quick look whether this can be made into an error instead of silently failing, because nobody reads the manual.  Unfortunately, this mechanism is not very generic, so I'd have to add error handling code to each and every shape in existence.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I had the same thoughts and conclusion, which can be found (implicitly) in the P.S. of the answer I wrote. In principle one could go a different way: issue a warning *unless* the shape border is rotatable. But this has other downsides, e.g. when users want to use the key in a `scope`, so it is probably not practical (either?).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat ...but nobody reads warnings either. I have a fat warning about voltage directions in `circuitikz` since, well, two years, and in questions (and answer) in this site nobody take notice... :-( (and lately, thanks to automatical and online services, people didn't even notice errors, unless you make the document explode... (hmmm))

Comment: @Rmano Well, at least for me this would have made a difference when I saw this behavior for the first time. And yes, these online tools, or more generally the attitude to throw users under the bus, are a problem, but at least from the Ti*k*Z/pgf side one could do better. Anyway, apparently Henri sees a way to make all shape boundaries rotatable, which would of course solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! The pgfmanual clearly says (on p, 231 of v3.1.5) that

> Some shapes (but not all), support a special kind of rotation. This
>   rotation affects only the border of a shape and is independent of the
>   node contents, but in addition to any other transformations.

The `tape` shape is not one of the shapes which are supported.

However, what you always can do is to use `fit`, along with the `rotate fit` key, to rotate the shape boundary. Since you also want to fill it, you may want to work with layers, e.g. use the `backgrounds` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=2cm] (F) {A39F 47CA\\\ldots};
    \scoped[on background layer]{
    \node[shape=tape,rotate fit=90, fit=(F),draw,
    fill=yellow!20] {};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. If you want to argue that there should be some more information, either a list of supported shapes or a warning that gets issued if the shape is not in the list, I would tend to agree. Whether or not it is possible to implement such things with reasonable efforts is another question.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful. 
I looked at the pgf manual on p323 (v3.1.5) and i would have expected the note you quoted to be somewhere with the explanation of the option `pgf/shape border rotate`. 
Also a list of supported shapes or a warning would have helped me, but I understand issues arising from throwing a warning under certain circumstances.

Comment: @user217894 There is some ongoing discussion under https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/815.